# React Table isLoading property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table-v6

I found this tutorial article about creating MERN project https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-create-your-first-mern-mongodb-express-js-react-js-and-node-js-stack-7e8b20463e66. All is working fine, but what I'm confused with this code inside `componentDidMount()` function in MoviesList.jsx file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import api from '../api'

import styled from 'styled-components'

import 'react-table/react-table.css'

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    padding: 0 40px 40px 40px;
`

class MoviesList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            movies: [],
            columns: [],
            isLoading: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })

        await api.getAllMovies().then(movies => {
            this.setState({
                movies: movies.data.data,
                isLoading: false,
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { movies, isLoading } = this.state
        console.log('TCL: MoviesList -> render -> movies', movies)

        const columns = [
            {
                Header: 'ID',
                accessor: '_id',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: 'Name',
                accessor: 'name',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: 'Rating',
                accessor: 'rating',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: 'Time',
                accessor: 'time',
                Cell: props => <span>{props.value.join(' / ')}</span>,
            },
        ]

        let showTable = true
        if (!movies.length) {
            showTable = false
        }

        return (
            <Wrapper>
                {showTable && (
                    <ReactTable
                        data={movies}
                        columns={columns}
                        loading={isLoading}
                        defaultPageSize={10}
                        showPageSizeOptions={true}
                        minRows={0}
                    />
                )}
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}

export default MoviesList
```

Why we have to set the isLoading: true in this code `this.setState({ isLoading: true })`, then set it back to false with this code :

```
await api.getAllMovies().then(movies => {
            this.setState({
                movies: movies.data.data,
                isLoading: false,
            })
        })
```

I've been struggling with this question for almost a week. I really need help in understanding this code. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow show the user that page is loading data and data hasn't been loaded yet. `ReactTable` has a property for this (`loading` and I think it also has `loadingText` too to display a message while loading/fetching data), so when you load your page, `isLoading` is set to `true`

When your `async/await` code finishes and data is fetched from url, the `isLoading` is set to `false` and `ReactTable` is updated accordingly.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In your case here the benefite is to aware your ReactTable component when data is available.

But in many cases you will use this to tell your users.
Hey I'm performing a task behind right now, while that task is ongoing you can show a spinner or a simple text like "please hold on we're veryfing your account" to let him know you actually performing a task and that improve UX.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I can understand it well, now.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore it, it is not necessary to the run the code.
even for the loader it is enough to check movies.length > 0, so remove it